# Is the + operator considered a function?

Tags: functions

A function takes input and produce output.

Now the + operator takes two inputs and produce one output, so is the + operator considered a function?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) may help.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes

Comment: $f(x,y) = z \iff x + y = z.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can consider a function with domain $\mathbb{R}^2$ and range $\mathbb{R}$ for defining this function(note that $\mathbb{R}$ can be replaced by any set closed under addition, how the + is defined. For eg, the set of natural numbers)